# How to Prevent Auto Scroll to top when user clicks on the particular list value.

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

This component is called by a Parent component which is further called by a Parent component. If you want I can provide that details also. I hope that I will get some cool suggestions/solutions. I am stuck at this and not getting how to get rid of this.

```
       import React from "react";
        import PropTypes from "prop-types";
        import moment from "moment";
        import { Scrollbars } from "react-custom-scrollbars";
        import _ from "lodash";
        const LOADER_USER_COUNT = 10;
        import { timeFormat } from "d3-time-format";
        import { timeHour } from "d3-time";
        import { scaleTime, scaleBand } from "d3-scale";
        import { axisTop } from "d3-axis";
        import Axis from "./Axis";
        import ReactToolTip from "react-tooltip";

        const DATEFORMAT = "YYYYMMDD";

        class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        }

    getNameList(options) {
        const {
        fullName,
        lastSeen,
        activeClass,
        showSelection,
        isChecked,
        userId,
        yScale
        } = options;
        let { handleUserSelection } = this.props;

        let checkBoxClass = showSelection
        ? "downloadCheckBox active"
        : "downloadCheckBox";
        isChecked ? (checkBoxClass += " selected") : "";
        let initials = fullName.split(" ");
        return (
        <g className="hoverClass">
            {/*{`0,${yScale(userId) - 5} 300,${yScale(userId) - 5} 300,${yScale(userId) + 44} 0,${yScale(userId) + 44} 0,${yScale(userId) - 5}`}*/}
            <polyline
            className="firstHover"
            points={`0,${yScale(userId) + 46} 300,${yScale(userId) + 46}`}
            style={{ fill: "none", stroke: "lightgrey", strokeWidth: "1" }}
            />
            <circle
            cx="35"
            cy={yScale(userId) + 17}
            r="17"
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="2"
            fill="none"
            className={`user-img ${activeClass}`}
            />
            <text
            x="26"
            y={yScale(userId) + 23}
            fill="black"
            className="employeeFNLN"
            >
            {initials[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                (initials[1] && initials[1].charAt(0)
                ? initials[1].charAt(0)
                : initials[0].charAt(1))}
            </text>
            <g className={`user-details ${activeClass}`}>
            <text x="57" y={yScale(userId) + 14} fill="black">
                {fullName}
            </text>
            <text x="57" y={yScale(userId) + 34} fill="black" className="time">
                {lastSeen}
            </text>
            </g>
            <circle
            cx="265"
            cy={yScale(userId) + 20}
            r="10"
            onClick={() => {
                handleUserSelection({ id: userId, checked: !isChecked });
            }}
            stroke="none"
            strokeWidth="1"
            className={checkBoxClass}
            />

            <polyline
            onClick={() => {
                handleUserSelection({ id: userId, checked: !isChecked });
            }}
            className="path check"
            fill="none"
            stroke="white"
            strokeWidth="1"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeMiterlimit="10"
            points={`260,${yScale(userId) + 22} 263,${yScale(userId) +
                25} 270,${yScale(userId) + 18}`}
            />
        </g>
        );
    }

    getLoadingList() {
        return (
        <ul
            className={"employee-list stats attendance col-3"}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
        >
            {[...Array(LOADER_USER_COUNT)].map((k, i) => {
            return (
                <li key={i} className="row user-item-loader">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <div className="user-img offline">
                    <div className="animated-background sb-avatar" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={`col-9 user-details`}>
                    <div className="animated-background user-name" />
                    <div className="animated-background last-seen" />
                </div>
                </li>
            );
            })}
        </ul>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const {
        loading,
        employees: emp,
        selectedUser,
        showSelection,
        selectedExecutives,
        showSelectAll,
        sortBy,
        isFieldForce,
        // isSidebarOn,
        // progress,
        date,
        // product,
        executives: { executivesObj },
        // filters: { sortBy },
        todayProgress: { checkins },
        userId,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        dateRange,
        mobileView,
        selectUser,
        selectSlice,
        timeDiff,
        assignmentData,
        selectOptionClassName,
        filterCount
        } = this.props;

        let axisStartDate = startDate;
        let axisEndDate = dateRange ? endDate : startDate;
        // let today = checkins[startDate];
        let _d = date === "today" ? moment().format(DATEFORMAT) : date;
        let employees = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emp));

        let emp2 = employees ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(employees)) : [];
        let { shiftMapping } = this.props.shifts;
        if (loading) {
        return this.getLoadingList();
        // return isFieldForce
        //   ? this.getLoadingList()
        //   : [
        //     // this.props.getSearchBar(this.props.search, this.props.product)},
        //     <div className="col-12 row">
        //       <div className="col-3 row">{this.getLoadingList()}</div>
        //       <div className="col-9 row">{/* <Slice userId={emp._id} date="today" /> */}</div>
        //     </div>
        //   ];
        }
        let userIds = [];

        axisStartDate === "today"
        ? (axisStartDate = moment().format(DATEFORMAT))
        : (axisStartDate = startDate);

        axisEndDate === "today"
        ? (axisEndDate = moment().format(DATEFORMAT))
        : (axisEndDate = endDate);

        let dynamicAxis = this.getDynamicValuesForAxis(
        shiftMapping,
        checkins[startDate],
        startDate
        );
        // const date = startDate;
        if (date != "today") {
        employees.forEach(e => {
            if (!e.userData[date]) {
            e.userData[date] = {
                userFirstSeen: undefined,
                userLatestTime: undefined
            };
            }
        });
        }

        if (sortBy === "lastseen") {
        employees.sort((a, b) => {
            if (!a.userData[date] || !b.userData[date]) return 0;
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userLatestTime &&
            !b.userData[date].userLatestTime
            ) {
            return 0;
            }
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userLatestTime &&
            b.userData[date].userLatestTime !== ""
            ) {
            return 1;
            }
            if (
            a.userData[date].userLatestTime !== "" &&
            !b.userData[date].userLatestTime
            ) {
            return -1;
            }
            if (
            a.userData[date].userLatestTime &&
            b.userData[date].userLatestTime
            ) {
            let keyA = new Date(a.userData[date].userLatestTime),
                keyB = new Date(b.userData[date].userLatestTime);
            // Compare the 2 dates
            if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
            if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
            return 0;
            }
        });
        } else if (sortBy === "firstseen") {
        employees.sort((a, b) => {
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userFirstSeen &&
            !b.userData[date].userFirstSeen
            ) {
            return 0;
            }
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userFirstSeen &&
            b.userData[date].userFirstSeen !== ""
            ) {
            return 1;
            }
            if (
            a.userData[date].userFirstSeen !== "" &&
            !b.userData[date].userFirstSeen
            ) {
            return -1;
            }
            if (a.userData[date].userFirstSeen && b.userData[date].userFirstSeen) {
            let keyA = new Date(a.userData[date].userFirstSeen),
                keyB = new Date(b.userData[date].userFirstSeen);
            // Compare the 2 dates
            if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
            if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
            return 0;
            }
        });
        }

        let axisStartTime = dynamicAxis.min;
        let axisEndTime = dynamicAxis.max;

        let userIDs = [];
        let progressObject = {};
        let progressObjectFinish = {};

        // console.log(today);
        if (userId && userId.length > 0) {
        userIDs = userId;
        userIDs.forEach(id => {
            progressObject[id] =
            (checkins[startDate] &&
                checkins[startDate][id] &&
                checkins[startDate][id].progress) ||
            [];
        });
        } else {
        emp2.map(exec => {
            userIDs.push(exec._id);
            let userData = executivesObj[exec._id][0].userData || {};
            if (!userData[startDate] || !userData[startDate].userFirstSeen)
            progressObjectFinish[exec._id] = true;
            else
            progressObjectFinish[exec._id] =
                checkins[startDate] &&
                checkins[startDate][exec._id] &&
                checkins[startDate][exec._id].isProgressFinished;
            // progressObject[exec._id] = today[exec._id] && today[exec._id].progress;
            progressObject[exec._id] =
            checkins[startDate] &&
            checkins[startDate][exec._id] &&
            checkins[startDate][exec._id].progress;
        });
        }

        employees.forEach(e => {
        userIds.push(e._id);
        });

        let xScale = scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(axisStartTime), new Date(axisEndTime)])
        // .range([0, this.props.containerWidth - (mobileView ? 0 : 50)]);
        .range([0, 800]);

        var xAxis = axisTop(xScale)
        .tickFormat(timeFormat("%I %p"))
        .ticks(timeHour.every(timeDiff));

        let svgHeight = 55.9841 * userIDs.length;

        let yScale = scaleBand()
        .domain(userIds)
        .range([0, 56 * userIds.length]);

        return (
        <div
            className={
            showSelection
                ? "employee-list stats attendance selection-height"
                : "employee-list stats attendance"
            }
        >
            {/* <ReactToolTip multiline={true} /> */}
            <svg
            width="100%"
            height={showSelection || filterCount ? "80" : "50"}
            viewBox="0 0 1200 1200"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
            <defs>
                <filter id="dropshadow" height="100%" width="100%">
                <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="20" dy="20" />
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <foreignObject height="50" width="25%">
                {this.props.getSearchBar(this.props.search, this.props.product)}
            </foreignObject>
            <g transform="translate(330, 30)">
                <Axis axis={xAxis} mobileView />
            </g>
            <foreignObject height="30" width="25%" y="50">
                {//employee usage only
                showSelection ? (
                <div className={selectOptionClassName}>
                    {selectedExecutives.length ? (
                    <span className="float-left selection-total">{`${
                        selectedExecutives.length
                    } selected`}</span>
                    ) : null}
                    {showSelectAll ? (
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleSelectAll}>
                        Select All
                    </a>
                    ) : null}
                    {selectedExecutives.length != 0 ? (
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleSelectNone}>
                        Clear
                    </a>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
                ) : filterCount ? (
                <div
                    key="filterCount"
                    className="pointer p-2 text-center"
                    style={{ color: "#adadad" }}
                    onClick={() => {
                    if (window.innerWidth < 573) {
                        //close menu sidebar
                        this.props.setSidebar(false);
                    }
                    this.props.openFilterNavigation(!this.props.filterSidebar);
                    }}
                >
                    <span className="position-relative">
                    <i className="fa fa-filter filter-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
                    {filterCount ? <span className="red-bubble" /> : null}
                    </span>{" "}
                    {filterCount} filter{filterCount > 1 ? "s" : ""} applied
                </div>
                ) : null}
            </foreignObject>
            </svg>
            <Scrollbars style={{ flex: "1 1 0" }}>
            <svg
                // width="100%"
                // height={svgHeight}
                viewBox={`0 0 1200 ${svgHeight}`}
                preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
                <g transform="translate(0, 10)">
                {employees.map((emp, index) => {
                    const userDetails = emp.userDetails;
                    const name = userDetails.name || {};
                    if (!name || !name.first) return;
                    const fullName = `${name.first} ${name.last}`;
                    {
                    /* const mobile = `${userDetails.isdCode}-${userDetails.mobile}`; */
                    }

                    const isChecked = selectedExecutives.indexOf(emp._id) !== -1;

                    let rowClass = "row";
                    const userId = emp._id;
                    let isSelected = false;
                    if (selectedUser._id === emp._id) {
                    isSelected = true;
                    rowClass += " active";
                    }
                    let lastSeen = "--";
                    let activeClass = "";
                    let key = "userLatestTime";
                    if (sortBy === "firstseen") key = "userFirstSeen";
                    if (
                    emp.userData[date] &&
                    emp.userData[date][key] &&
                    (moment(emp.userData[date][key]).isAfter(
                        moment().startOf("day")
                    ) ||
                        date !== "today")
                    ) {
                    let tempDate = moment(emp.userData[date][key]);
                    if (tempDate && tempDate._isValid == true) {
                        lastSeen = tempDate.format("hh:mm A");
                        if (date !== "today") lastSeen = tempDate.format("lll");
                    }
                    // if (emp.zero["30"]) activeClass += " late";
                    } else if (
                    emp.userData[date].userLastTime &&
                    sortBy != "firstseen"
                    ) {
                    activeClass = "offline";
                    let tempDate = moment(emp.userData[date].userLastTime);
                    if (tempDate && tempDate._isValid == true) {
                        lastSeen = tempDate.format("Do MMM, YYYY hh:mm A");
                    }
                    } else {
                    activeClass = "offline";
                    }
                    if (emp.noSavedLocation && this.props.isLiteVersion) {
                    if (!emp.userData[date].userLatestTime)
                        activeClass = "offline";
                    }
                    return (
                    <g
                        key={index}
                        className="row-element"
                        // onMouseEnter={() => this.handleHover(index, true)}
                        // onMouseLeave={() => this.handleHover(index, false)}
                        ref={"gTag" + index}
                    >
                        <g
                        className={`${rowClass} single-user ${
                            isSelected ? "svg-selected-user" : ""
                        }`}
                        key={emp._id}
                        onClick={() => {
                            if (showSelection) return; // can't select when you are downloading csv
                            if (!isSelected) {
                            this.props.selectUser(emp);
                            if (window.location) {
                                window.location.hash = "#" + emp._id;
                            }
                            } else {
                            this.props.resetUserSelection();
                            if (window.location) window.location.hash = "";
                            }
                        }}
                        style={{
                            padding: "0 !important",
                            pointerEvents: "bounding-box"
                        }}
                        >
                        {/*group for name box*/}
                        {this.getNameList({
                            fullName,
                            lastSeen,
                            activeClass,
                            showSelection,
                            isChecked,
                            userId,
                            yScale
                        })}
                        </g>
                        <g transform="translate(280, 0)">
                        {/*group for attendance timeline*/}
                        {progressObject[emp._id] &&
                            progressObject[emp._id].map((slice, _i) => {
                            let width =
                                xScale(new Date(slice.end)) -
                                xScale(new Date(slice.start)) +
                                1;
                            let timeSpent = moment(slice.end)
                                .set("millisecond", 0)
                                .diff(
                                moment(slice.start).set("millisecond", 0),
                                "seconds"
                                );
                            let _timeSpent = moment()
                                .startOf("day")
                                .seconds(timeSpent);
                            if (timeSpent < 60)
                                _timeSpent = _timeSpent.format("ss[s]");
                            else if (timeSpent < 3600)
                                _timeSpent = _timeSpent.format("mm[m] ss[s]");
                            else
                                _timeSpent = _timeSpent.format("HH[h] mm[m] ss[s]");
                            let tooltip =
                                "From: " +
                                moment(slice.start).format("lll") +
                                " to " +
                                moment(slice.end).format("lll") +
                                "<br/>Time Spent: " +
                                _timeSpent +
                                (slice.status
                                ? `<br/> status: ${slice.status.toUpperCase()}`
                                : "");
                            const _s = slice;
                            const progressIndex = _i;
                            return (
                                <rect
                                onClick={() => {
                                    // let _emp = executivesObj[emp._id][0];
                                    selectSlice(_s);
                                    selectUser(emp, progressIndex);
                                    if (window.location)
                                    window.location.hash = "#" + emp._id;
                                }}
                                x={xScale(new Date(slice.start)) + 50}
                                y={yScale(emp._id) + 10}
                                height={10}
                                width={width < 0 ? 0 : width}
                                rx={2}
                                ry={2}
                                key={_i}
                                style={{
                                    fill: slice.color
                                    ? slice.color
                                    : "rgb(78, 198, 84)"
                                }}
                                data-tip={tooltip}
                                />
                            );
                            })}
                        {!progressObject[emp._id] ||
                        progressObject[emp._id].length === 0 ? (
                            progressObjectFinish[emp._id] ? (
                            <text x="5%" y={yScale(emp._id) + 30} fill="#ccc">
                                {" "}
                                No data available
                            </text>
                            ) : (
                            <text x="5%" y={yScale(emp._id) + 30} fill="#ccc">
                                {" "}
                                Loading...
                            </text>
                            )
                        ) : null}
                        </g>
                        <line
                        x1="0"
                        y1={yScale(userId) + 46}
                        x2="100%"
                        y2={yScale(userId) + 46}
                        style={{ stroke: "lightgrey", strokeWidth: "1" }}
                        />
                        <line
                        x1="300"
                        y1="0"
                        x2="300"
                        y2="100%"
                        style={{ stroke: "lightgrey", strokeWidth: "2" }}
                        />
                    </g>
                    );
                })}
                </g>
            </svg>
            {employees.length === 0 ? (
                <h5 className="text-center mt-2">No Data Found</h5>
            ) : null}
            </Scrollbars>
        </div>
        );
    }

    getDynamicValuesForAxis(shiftMapping, todayProgress, date) {
        if (Object.keys(shiftMapping).length && todayProgress != undefined) {
        let retVal = {
            min: undefined,
            max: undefined
        };

        if (date === "today") {
            date = moment().format(DATEFORMAT);
        }

        let shiftTiming = [];
        _.each(shiftMapping, shift => {
            if (shift.dObjectDetails.enabled === false) return;
            shiftTiming.push({
            startHour: parseInt(shift.dObjectData.start_hour),
            endHour: parseInt(shift.dObjectData.end_hour)
            });
        });

        let shiftSort = _.sortBy(shiftTiming, el => {
            return el.startHour;
        });

        retVal = {
            min: moment(date, DATEFORMAT)
            .hour(shiftSort[0].startHour)
            .minute(0),
            max:
            shiftSort[shiftSort.length - 1].endHour < shiftSort[0].startHour
                ? moment(date, DATEFORMAT)
                    .add(1, "day")
                    .hour(shiftSort[shiftSort.length - 1].endHour)
                    .minute(0)
                : moment(date, DATEFORMAT)
                    .hour(shiftSort[shiftSort.length - 1].endHour)
                    .minute(0)
        };

        let startObject = [],
            endObject = [];

        _.each(todayProgress, el => {
            el &&
            el.progress &&
            el.progress.length &&
            startObject.push(el.progress[0]);
            el.progress &&
            el.progress.length &&
            endObject.push(el.progress[el.progress.length - 1]);
        });

        startObject = _.sortBy(startObject, el => {
            if (el) return el.start;
        });

        endObject = _.sortBy(endObject, el => {
            if (el) return el.end;
        });

        if (
            startObject[0] &&
            startObject[0].start &&
            moment(retVal.min).isAfter(moment(startObject[0].start))
        ) {
            retVal.min = moment(startObject[0].start);
        }

        if (
            endObject[endObject.length - 1] &&
            endObject[endObject.length - 1].end &&
            moment(retVal.max).isBefore(moment(endObject[endObject.length - 1].end))
        ) {
            retVal.max = moment(endObject[endObject.length - 1].end);
        }

        return retVal;
        } else {
        return {
            min: moment(date, DATEFORMAT).startOf("day"),
            max: moment(date, DATEFORMAT).endOf("day")
        };
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        ReactToolTip.rebuild();
    }

    // handleHover(item, hover) {
    //   // console.log("g tag style from hover:::::", this.refs["gTag" + item].style);
    //   hover ? (this.refs["gTag" + item].style.filter = "url(#dropshadow)") : (this.refs["gTag" + item].style = "");
    // }
    }

    EmployeeList.propTypes = {
    selectedUser: PropTypes.object,
    progress: PropTypes.object,
    assignmentData: PropTypes.object,
    resetUserSelection: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    handleUserSelection: PropTypes.func,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    employees: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    showSelection: PropTypes.bool,
    isFieldForce: PropTypes.bool,
    sortBy: PropTypes.string,
    date: PropTypes.string,
    product: PropTypes.string,
    selectedExecutives: PropTypes.array,
    isSidebarOn: PropTypes.bool,
    isLiteVersion: PropTypes.bool,
    };

    export default EmployeeList;
```

Please suggest me that, why it is getting auto scroll to the top? I am stuck at this. Every suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you trim down your code? It's tough to get through the markup

Answer (score 0):

in your onClick try

```
onClick={(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  handleUserSelection({ id: userId, checked: !isChecked });
}}
```

Also, the href="#" on anchor tags looks for an ID on the page and will likely scroll you to the top on click.

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleSelectAll}>
    Select All
</a>
```

Comment: I tried that before shooting my question here. No luck yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is working. I am using ref for setting the scroll position and it is working fine .

```
 import React from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import moment from "moment";
    import { Scrollbars } from "react-custom-scrollbars";
    import _ from "lodash";
    const LOADER_USER_COUNT = 10;
    import { timeFormat } from "d3-time-format";
    import { timeHour } from "d3-time";
    import { scaleTime, scaleBand } from "d3-scale";
    import { axisTop } from "d3-axis";
    import Axis from "./Axis";
    import ReactToolTip from "react-tooltip";

    const DATEFORMAT = "YYYYMMDD";

    class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    getNameList(options) {
        const {
        fullName,
        lastSeen,
        activeClass,
        showSelection,
        isChecked,
        userId,
        yScale
        } = options;
        let { handleUserSelection } = this.props;

        let checkBoxClass = showSelection
        ? "downloadCheckBox active"
        : "downloadCheckBox";
        isChecked ? (checkBoxClass += " selected") : "";
        let initials = fullName.split(" ");
        return (
        <g className="hoverClass">
            {/*{`0,${yScale(userId) - 5} 300,${yScale(userId) - 5} 300,${yScale(userId) + 44} 0,${yScale(userId) + 44} 0,${yScale(userId) - 5}`}*/}
            <polyline
            className="firstHover"
            points={`0,${yScale(userId) + 46} 300,${yScale(userId) + 46}`}
            style={{ fill: "none", stroke: "lightgrey", strokeWidth: "1" }}
            />
            <circle
            cx="35"
            cy={yScale(userId) + 17}
            r="17"
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="2"
            fill="none"
            className={`user-img ${activeClass}`}
            />
            <text
            x="26"
            y={yScale(userId) + 23}
            fill="black"
            className="employeeFNLN"
            >
            {initials[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                (initials[1] && initials[1].charAt(0)
                ? initials[1].charAt(0)
                : initials[0].charAt(1))}
            </text>
            <g className={`user-details ${activeClass}`}>
            <text x="57" y={yScale(userId) + 14} fill="black">
                {fullName}
            </text>
            <text x="57" y={yScale(userId) + 34} fill="black" className="time">
                {lastSeen}
            </text>
            </g>
            <circle
            cx="265"
            cy={yScale(userId) + 20}
            r="10"
            onClick={() => {
                handleUserSelection({ id: userId, checked: !isChecked });
            }}
            stroke="none"
            strokeWidth="1"
            className={checkBoxClass}
            />

            <polyline
            onClick={() => {
                handleUserSelection({ id: userId, checked: !isChecked });
            }}
            className="path check"
            fill="none"
            stroke="white"
            strokeWidth="1"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeMiterlimit="10"
            points={`260,${yScale(userId) + 22} 263,${yScale(userId) +
                25} 270,${yScale(userId) + 18}`}
            />
        </g>
        );
    }

    getLoadingList() {
        return (
        <ul
            className={"employee-list stats attendance col-3"}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
        >
            {[...Array(LOADER_USER_COUNT)].map((k, i) => {
            return (
                <li key={i} className="row user-item-loader">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <div className="user-img offline">
                    <div className="animated-background sb-avatar" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={`col-9 user-details`}>
                    <div className="animated-background user-name" />
                    <div className="animated-background last-seen" />
                </div>
                </li>
            );
            })}
        </ul>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const {
        loading,
        employees: emp,
        selectedUser,
        showSelection,
        selectedExecutives,
        showSelectAll,
        sortBy,
        isFieldForce,
        // isSidebarOn,
        // progress,
        date,
        // product,
        executives: { executivesObj },
        // filters: { sortBy },
        todayProgress: { checkins },
        userId,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        dateRange,
        mobileView,
        selectUser,
        selectSlice,
        timeDiff,
        assignmentData,
        selectOptionClassName,
        filterCount
        } = this.props;

        let axisStartDate = startDate;
        let axisEndDate = dateRange ? endDate : startDate;
        // let today = checkins[startDate];
        let _d = date === "today" ? moment().format(DATEFORMAT) : date;
        let employees = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emp));

        let emp2 = employees ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(employees)) : [];
        let { shiftMapping } = this.props.shifts;
        if (loading) {
        return this.getLoadingList();
        // return isFieldForce
        //   ? this.getLoadingList()
        //   : [
        //     // this.props.getSearchBar(this.props.search, this.props.product)},
        //     <div className="col-12 row">
        //       <div className="col-3 row">{this.getLoadingList()}</div>
        //       <div className="col-9 row">{/* <Slice userId={emp._id} date="today" /> */}</div>
        //     </div>
        //   ];
        }
        let userIds = [];

        axisStartDate === "today"
        ? (axisStartDate = moment().format(DATEFORMAT))
        : (axisStartDate = startDate);

        axisEndDate === "today"
        ? (axisEndDate = moment().format(DATEFORMAT))
        : (axisEndDate = endDate);

        let dynamicAxis = this.getDynamicValuesForAxis(
        shiftMapping,
        checkins[startDate],
        startDate
        );
        // const date = startDate;
        if (date != "today") {
        employees.forEach(e => {
            if (!e.userData[date]) {
            e.userData[date] = {
                userFirstSeen: undefined,
                userLatestTime: undefined
            };
            }
        });
        }

        if (sortBy === "lastseen") {
        employees.sort((a, b) => {
            if (!a.userData[date] || !b.userData[date]) return 0;
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userLatestTime &&
            !b.userData[date].userLatestTime
            ) {
            return 0;
            }
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userLatestTime &&
            b.userData[date].userLatestTime !== ""
            ) {
            return 1;
            }
            if (
            a.userData[date].userLatestTime !== "" &&
            !b.userData[date].userLatestTime
            ) {
            return -1;
            }
            if (
            a.userData[date].userLatestTime &&
            b.userData[date].userLatestTime
            ) {
            let keyA = new Date(a.userData[date].userLatestTime),
                keyB = new Date(b.userData[date].userLatestTime);
            // Compare the 2 dates
            if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
            if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
            return 0;
            }
        });
        } else if (sortBy === "firstseen") {
        employees.sort((a, b) => {
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userFirstSeen &&
            !b.userData[date].userFirstSeen
            ) {
            return 0;
            }
            if (
            !a.userData[date].userFirstSeen &&
            b.userData[date].userFirstSeen !== ""
            ) {
            return 1;
            }
            if (
            a.userData[date].userFirstSeen !== "" &&
            !b.userData[date].userFirstSeen
            ) {
            return -1;
            }
            if (a.userData[date].userFirstSeen && b.userData[date].userFirstSeen) {
            let keyA = new Date(a.userData[date].userFirstSeen),
                keyB = new Date(b.userData[date].userFirstSeen);
            // Compare the 2 dates
            if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
            if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
            return 0;
            }
        });
        }

        let axisStartTime = dynamicAxis.min;
        let axisEndTime = dynamicAxis.max;

        let userIDs = [];
        let progressObject = {};
        let progressObjectFinish = {};

        // console.log(today);
        if (userId && userId.length > 0) {
        userIDs = userId;
        userIDs.forEach(id => {
            progressObject[id] =
            (checkins[startDate] &&
                checkins[startDate][id] &&
                checkins[startDate][id].progress) ||
            [];
        });
        } else {
        emp2.map(exec => {
            userIDs.push(exec._id);
            let userData = executivesObj[exec._id][0].userData || {};
            if (!userData[startDate] || !userData[startDate].userFirstSeen)
            progressObjectFinish[exec._id] = true;
            else
            progressObjectFinish[exec._id] =
                checkins[startDate] &&
                checkins[startDate][exec._id] &&
                checkins[startDate][exec._id].isProgressFinished;
            // progressObject[exec._id] = today[exec._id] && today[exec._id].progress;
            progressObject[exec._id] =
            checkins[startDate] &&
            checkins[startDate][exec._id] &&
            checkins[startDate][exec._id].progress;
        });
        }

        employees.forEach(e => {
        userIds.push(e._id);
        });

        let xScale = scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(axisStartTime), new Date(axisEndTime)])
        // .range([0, this.props.containerWidth - (mobileView ? 0 : 50)]);
        .range([0, 800]);

        var xAxis = axisTop(xScale)
        .tickFormat(timeFormat("%I %p"))
        .ticks(timeHour.every(timeDiff));

        let svgHeight = 55.9841 * userIDs.length;

        let yScale = scaleBand()
        .domain(userIds)
        .range([0, 56 * userIds.length]);

        let _scrollTop = 0;

        return (
        <div
            className={
            showSelection
                ? "employee-list stats attendance selection-height"
                : "employee-list stats attendance"
            }
        >
            {/* <ReactToolTip multiline={true} /> */}
            <svg
            width="100%"
            height={showSelection || filterCount ? "80" : "50"}
            viewBox="0 0 1200 1200"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
            <defs>
                <filter id="dropshadow" height="100%" width="100%">
                <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="20" dy="20" />
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <foreignObject height="50" width="25%">
                {this.props.getSearchBar(this.props.search, this.props.product)}
            </foreignObject>
            <g transform="translate(330, 30)">
                <Axis axis={xAxis} mobileView />
            </g>
            <foreignObject height="30" width="25%" y="50">
                {//employee usage only
                showSelection ? (
                <div className={selectOptionClassName}>
                    {selectedExecutives.length ? (
                    <span className="float-left selection-total">{`${
                        selectedExecutives.length
                    } selected`}</span>
                    ) : null}
                    {showSelectAll ? (
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleSelectAll}>
                        Select All
                    </a>
                    ) : null}
                    {selectedExecutives.length != 0 ? (
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleSelectNone}>
                        Clear
                    </a>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
                ) : filterCount ? (
                <div
                    key="filterCount"
                    className="pointer p-2 text-center"
                    style={{ color: "#adadad" }}
                    onClick={() => {
                    if (window.innerWidth < 573) {
                        //close menu sidebar
                        this.props.setSidebar(false);
                    }
                    this.props.openFilterNavigation(!this.props.filterSidebar);
                    }}
                >
                    <span className="position-relative">
                    <i className="fa fa-filter filter-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
                    {filterCount ? <span className="red-bubble" /> : null}
                    </span>{" "}
                    {filterCount} filter{filterCount > 1 ? "s" : ""} applied
                </div>
                ) : null}
            </foreignObject>
            </svg>
            <Scrollbars
            onScrollFrame={values => {
                let { scrollTop } = values;
                _scrollTop = scrollTop;
            }}
            style={{ flex: "1 1 0" }}
            ref={ref => {
                if (ref) {
                ref.scrollTop(_scrollTop || this.props.scrollTop);
                }
            }}
            >
            <svg
                // width="100%"
                // height={svgHeight}
                viewBox={`0 0 1200 ${svgHeight}`}
                preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
                <g transform="translate(0, 10)">
                {employees.map((emp, index) => {
                    const userDetails = emp.userDetails;
                    const name = userDetails.name || {};
                    if (!name || !name.first) return;
                    const fullName = `${name.first} ${name.last}`;
                    {
                    /* const mobile = `${userDetails.isdCode}-${userDetails.mobile}`; */
                    }

                    const isChecked = selectedExecutives.indexOf(emp._id) !== -1;

                    let rowClass = "row";
                    const userId = emp._id;
                    let isSelected = false;
                    if (selectedUser._id === emp._id) {
                    isSelected = true;
                    rowClass += " active";
                    }
                    let lastSeen = "--";
                    let activeClass = "";
                    let key = "userLatestTime";
                    if (sortBy === "firstseen") key = "userFirstSeen";
                    if (
                    emp.userData[date] &&
                    emp.userData[date][key] &&
                    (moment(emp.userData[date][key]).isAfter(
                        moment().startOf("day")
                    ) ||
                        date !== "today")
                    ) {
                    let tempDate = moment(emp.userData[date][key]);
                    if (tempDate && tempDate._isValid == true) {
                        lastSeen = tempDate.format("hh:mm A");
                        if (date !== "today") lastSeen = tempDate.format("lll");
                    }
                    // if (emp.zero["30"]) activeClass += " late";
                    } else if (
                    emp.userData[date].userLastTime &&
                    sortBy != "firstseen"
                    ) {
                    activeClass = "offline";
                    let tempDate = moment(emp.userData[date].userLastTime);
                    if (tempDate && tempDate._isValid == true) {
                        lastSeen = tempDate.format("Do MMM, YYYY hh:mm A");
                    }
                    } else {
                    activeClass = "offline";
                    }
                    if (emp.noSavedLocation && this.props.isLiteVersion) {
                    if (!emp.userData[date].userLatestTime)
                        activeClass = "offline";
                    }
                    return (
                    <g
                        key={index}
                        className="row-element"
                        // onMouseEnter={() => this.handleHover(index, true)}
                        // onMouseLeave={() => this.handleHover(index, false)}
                        ref={"gTag" + index}
                    >
                        <g
                        className={`${rowClass} single-user ${
                            isSelected ? "svg-selected-user" : ""
                        }`}
                        key={emp._id}
                        onClick={() => {
                            if (showSelection) return; // can't select when you are downloading csv
                            this.props.setScroll(_scrollTop);
                            if (!isSelected) {
                            selectUser(emp);
                            //need value of scroll
                            if (window.location) {
                                window.location.hash = "#" + emp._id;
                            }
                            } else {
                            this.props.resetUserSelection();
                            if (window.location) window.location.hash = "";
                            }
                        }}
                        style={{
                            padding: "0 !important",
                            pointerEvents: "bounding-box"
                        }}
                        >
                        {/*group for name box*/}
                        {this.getNameList({
                            fullName,
                            lastSeen,
                            activeClass,
                            showSelection,
                            isChecked,
                            userId,
                            yScale
                        })}
                        </g>
                        <g transform="translate(280, 0)">
                        {/*group for attendance timeline*/}
                        {progressObject[emp._id] &&
                            progressObject[emp._id].map((slice, _i) => {
                            let width =
                                xScale(new Date(slice.end)) -
                                xScale(new Date(slice.start)) +
                                1;
                            let timeSpent = moment(slice.end)
                                .set("millisecond", 0)
                                .diff(
                                moment(slice.start).set("millisecond", 0),
                                "seconds"
                                );
                            let _timeSpent = moment()
                                .startOf("day")
                                .seconds(timeSpent);
                            if (timeSpent < 60)
                                _timeSpent = _timeSpent.format("ss[s]");
                            else if (timeSpent < 3600)
                                _timeSpent = _timeSpent.format("mm[m] ss[s]");
                            else
                                _timeSpent = _timeSpent.format("HH[h] mm[m] ss[s]");
                            let tooltip =
                                "From: " +
                                moment(slice.start).format("lll") +
                                " to " +
                                moment(slice.end).format("lll") +
                                "<br/>Time Spent: " +
                                _timeSpent +
                                (slice.status
                                ? `<br/> status: ${slice.status.toUpperCase()}`
                                : "");
                            const _s = slice;
                            const progressIndex = _i;
                            return (
                                <rect
                                onClick={() => {
                                    // let _emp = executivesObj[emp._id][0];
                                    selectSlice(_s);
                                    selectUser(emp, progressIndex);
                                    this.props.setScroll(_scrollTop);
                                    if (window.location)
                                    window.location.hash = "#" + emp._id;
                                }}
                                x={xScale(new Date(slice.start)) + 50}
                                y={yScale(emp._id) + 10}
                                height={10}
                                width={width < 0 ? 0 : width}
                                rx={2}
                                ry={2}
                                key={_i}
                                style={{
                                    fill: slice.color
                                    ? slice.color
                                    : "rgb(78, 198, 84)"
                                }}
                                data-tip={tooltip}
                                />
                            );
                            })}
                        {!progressObject[emp._id] ||
                        progressObject[emp._id].length === 0 ? (
                            progressObjectFinish[emp._id] ? (
                            <text x="5%" y={yScale(emp._id) + 30} fill="#ccc">
                                {" "}
                                No data available
                            </text>
                            ) : (
                            <text x="5%" y={yScale(emp._id) + 30} fill="#ccc">
                                {" "}
                                Loading...
                            </text>
                            )
                        ) : null}
                        </g>
                        <line
                        x1="0"
                        y1={yScale(userId) + 46}
                        x2="100%"
                        y2={yScale(userId) + 46}
                        style={{ stroke: "lightgrey", strokeWidth: "1" }}
                        />
                        <line
                        x1="300"
                        y1="0"
                        x2="300"
                        y2="100%"
                        style={{ stroke: "lightgrey", strokeWidth: "2" }}
                        />
                    </g>
                    );
                })}
                </g>
            </svg>
            {employees.length === 0 ? (
                <h5 className="text-center mt-2">No Data Found</h5>
            ) : null}
            </Scrollbars>
        </div>
        );
    }

    getDynamicValuesForAxis(shiftMapping, todayProgress, date) {
        if (Object.keys(shiftMapping).length && todayProgress != undefined) {
        let retVal = {
            min: undefined,
            max: undefined
        };

        if (date === "today") {
            date = moment().format(DATEFORMAT);
        }

        let shiftTiming = [];
        _.each(shiftMapping, shift => {
            if (shift.dObjectDetails.enabled === false) return;
            shiftTiming.push({
            startHour: parseInt(shift.dObjectData.start_hour),
            endHour: parseInt(shift.dObjectData.end_hour)
            });
        });

        let shiftSort = _.sortBy(shiftTiming, el => {
            return el.startHour;
        });

        retVal = {
            min: moment(date, DATEFORMAT)
            .hour(shiftSort[0].startHour)
            .minute(0),
            max:
            shiftSort[shiftSort.length - 1].endHour < shiftSort[0].startHour
                ? moment(date, DATEFORMAT)
                    .add(1, "day")
                    .hour(shiftSort[shiftSort.length - 1].endHour)
                    .minute(0)
                : moment(date, DATEFORMAT)
                    .hour(shiftSort[shiftSort.length - 1].endHour)
                    .minute(0)
        };

        let startObject = [],
            endObject = [];

        _.each(todayProgress, el => {
            el &&
            el.progress &&
            el.progress.length &&
            startObject.push(el.progress[0]);
            el.progress &&
            el.progress.length &&
            endObject.push(el.progress[el.progress.length - 1]);
        });

        startObject = _.sortBy(startObject, el => {
            if (el) return el.start;
        });

        endObject = _.sortBy(endObject, el => {
            if (el) return el.end;
        });

        if (
            startObject[0] &&
            startObject[0].start &&
            moment(retVal.min).isAfter(moment(startObject[0].start))
        ) {
            retVal.min = moment(startObject[0].start);
        }

        if (
            endObject[endObject.length - 1] &&
            endObject[endObject.length - 1].end &&
            moment(retVal.max).isBefore(moment(endObject[endObject.length - 1].end))
        ) {
            retVal.max = moment(endObject[endObject.length - 1].end);
        }

        return retVal;
        } else {
        return {
            min: moment(date, DATEFORMAT).startOf("day"),
            max: moment(date, DATEFORMAT).endOf("day")
        };
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        ReactToolTip.rebuild();
    }

    // handleHover(item, hover) {
    //   // console.log("g tag style from hover:::::", this.refs["gTag" + item].style);
    //   hover ? (this.refs["gTag" + item].style.filter = "url(#dropshadow)") : (this.refs["gTag" + item].style = "");
    // }
    }

    EmployeeList.propTypes = {
    selectedUser: PropTypes.object,
    progress: PropTypes.object,
    assignmentData: PropTypes.object,
    resetUserSelection: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    handleUserSelection: PropTypes.func,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    employees: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    showSelection: PropTypes.bool,
    isFieldForce: PropTypes.bool,
    sortBy: PropTypes.string,
    date: PropTypes.string,
    product: PropTypes.string,
    selectedExecutives: PropTypes.array,
    isSidebarOn: PropTypes.bool,
    isLiteVersion: PropTypes.bool
    };

    export default EmployeeList;
```